# Linearly independent subset from subset of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a vector space, let $S\subseteq X$ be a non empty subset, not equal to $\{0\}$.

> Is it always possible to find a linearly independent subset $G\subseteq S$ such that $\text{span}(G)=\text{span}(S)?$

Here is an attempt of proof: the set $\{G | G\subseteq S $ is linearly independent$\}$ satisfies the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma, so there is a maximal element $G$.
If there was $s\in \text{span}(S)\setminus \text{span}(G)$ then $s=\sum_{i=1}^Na_is_i$, for $s_i \in S$, $a_i$ in the ground field. Since $s \notin \text{span}(G)$ there must be $s_j \notin \text{span}(G)$ for some $j=1,...,N$. By taking $G \cup \{s_j\}$ we contradict the maximality of $G$.

Is everything fine?

Comment: Yes, it looks good.